# how to build ms access first() function in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

How do I re-build the following MS Access query that has the First() function for almost all the columns in the select list in SQL Server 2008 R2? The MS Access query returns 254 records and the SQL query I built without the First() function return 545 records which is obviously not returning the desired results. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 
First(Acct_ID) AS FirstOfAcct_ID, 
First(IMDX__ID) AS FirstOfIMDX_ID, 
First(Referral_ID) AS FirstOfReferral_ID, 
First(FIRSTNAME) AS FirstOfFIRSTNAME
First(LASTNAME) AS FirstOfLASTNAME, 
First(ADDRESSLINE1) AS FirstOfADDRESSLINE1, 
First(ADDRESSLINE2) AS FirstOfADDRESSLINE2, 
First(CITY) AS FirstOfCITY, 
First(STATE) AS FirstOfSTATE, 
First(ZIPCODE) AS FirstOfZIPCODE, 
First(Acct_Office_ID) AS FirstOfAcct_Office_ID, 
First(IMDX_Office_ID) AS FirstOfIMDX_Office_ID, 
FROM <<TableName>>
GROUP BY ZIPCODE,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,Acct_Office_ID,IMDX_Office_ID
HAVING (((First(posdesc)) Is Not Null) AND ((ACTIVE)<>0) AND ((CP_Active)<>0));
```

Comment: What do you think FIRST() means?

Comment: FIRST() means the first row returned in a dataset.

Comment: "First" depends on the ORDER BY, which your current query doesn't have. In SQL Server, a table is an unordered bag of rows. Imagine your are standing outside of a room, and someone drops a bag of marbles onto the floor. Can you enter the room and tell me which red marble hit the floor first?

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your input Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT Acct_ID, IMDX__ID, ... other columns ..., rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY ZIPCODE, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, Acct_Office_ID, IMDX_Office_ID
   ORDER BY ... whatever column(s) you think FIRST() means ...)
  FROM dbo.TableName
  WHERE posdesc IS NOT NULL AND ACTIVE <> 0 AND CP_Active <> 0
)
SELECT ... all columns except rn ... FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: What does the "PARTITION BY" statement do in this context? I am trying to understand and learn. Thanks!

Comment: @narry It's similar to what your original GROUP BY was doing.